# Writing dataframe to SQL - can't connect to server

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy

So I'm trying to use the to_sql command to write records stored in a DataFrame to a SQL database using sqlalchemy.

I have mySQL installed

I have a dataframe called `df`

**What I've tried:**

First I created a schema in mySQL workbench called "task_db", then:

```
import pandas as pd

import sqlalchemy
import pymysql
import sqlalchemy as db

engine = db.create_engine("mysql+pymysql://myusername:mypassword@3306/task_db")

df.to_sql("result", engine, schema=None, if_exists="fail", index=True, index_label=None, chunksize=None, dtype=None, method=None)
```

In the errors it mentions several times "Can't connect to MySQL server on '3306'", but that is the localhost I got showing on mySQL workbench.

Comment: Have you tried replacing 3306 with localhost:3306?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't declare this `localhost` anywhere. Try this connection string: `mysql+pymysql://myusername:mypassword@localhost/task_db?host=localhost?port=3306`

Comment: That was the problem indeed. Thank you!